# EditText getText not working in Button Click

Tags: java, android

I have two EditText in MyActivity. Here I have provided UI XML.

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_insta"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
                android:text="Download"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editUrli"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#0C0C0C"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="177dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="81dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="81dp"
                android:text="Paste Instagram video link to download "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="43dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:src="@drawable/insta"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editUrl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#0C0C0C"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_download"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_download"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
                android:text="Download"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fblogo"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
                android:contentDescription="TODO"
                android:src="@drawable/fb"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editUrl"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="84dp"
                android:text="Paste FB video link to download"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_download"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fblogo"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

In my Activity java code has this button click code

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);
        
        inputURl = findViewById(R.id.editUrl);
        editUrlinsta = findViewById(R.id.editUrli);

        BtnDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_download);
        downloadinsta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_insta);

        BtnDownload.setOnClickListener(this);
        downloadinsta.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.button_download:
                    try{
                       
                        final FacebookDownloader downloaders = new FacebookDownloader(Download.this,inputURl.getText().toString());
                        downloaders.DownloadVideo();
                        inputURl.getText().clear();
                    } catch(Exception e) {}
                    break;
                case R.id.button_insta:
                        final InstaDownloader downloaderInsta = new InstaDownloader(Download.this,editUrlinsta.getText().toString());
                        downloaderInsta.DownloadVideo();
                        editUrlinsta.getText().clear();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
    
            }
        }
```

The problem is The first button which I have named `button_download` is working as expected. But the second button `button_insta` not working as expected. what I want to do, is When one of the buttons clicks, getting data from EditText. The  `button_download` works fine. the `button_insta` is not working fine.
I couldn't get value from `editUrli` when the button click. But same code works for `button_download` and `editUrl`

Comment: I think there is a problem in your InstaDownloder. Wrap the code in try catch block and print the stackTrace

Comment: @PankajSati I don't think so Because I directly passed some value to InstaDownloader. It worked and same time I put a Log.d to debug those worked in try block. I'm pretty much sure the issue is not InstaDownloader.

Comment: check whether your download url is correct or not.

Comment: They are correct. The problem is a value not getting from editText of `editUrli`.

Comment: Your code is looking fine, Try to print values from edittext in log and try to log while button press. There must be some another issue.

Comment: Yes. I tried it after you had told me. while button press it's not getting a value from EditText. printed value is null even there had text.

Answer (score 1):

Try to separate those button click function like so :

```
BtnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    final FacebookDownloader downloaders = new FacebookDownloader(Download.this,inputURl.getText().toString());
                    downloaders.DownloadVideo();
                    inputURl.getText().clear();
                } catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        });

downloadinsta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final InstaDownloader downloaderInsta = new InstaDownloader(Download.this,editUrlinsta.getText().toString());
                    downloaderInsta.DownloadVideo();
                    editUrlinsta.getText().clear();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried this as well. not work. It's weird

Comment: Try `Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this, editUrlinsta, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` inside your `downloadinsta.setOnClickListener` to see if your code actually gets the value of `editUrlsinta`.

Comment: Did the toast show your `editUrlinsta` value?

Comment: Yes, I did. but the value was null.